# How can I plot this signal with DiscretePlot?

Tags: plotting, functions

How can I plot this signal with DiscretePlot?

[image]

This mean:

```
x[-2] = 3, x[-1] = -1, x[0] = 0, etc
```

This doesn't produce the desired output.

```
DiscretePlot[{3, -1, 0, -2, 1, -2, -4, 0, 
  1}, {n, {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}]
```

Comment: `ListPlot[
 Transpose[{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, -1, 0, -2, 1, -2, -4, 
    0, 1}}], Filling -> Axis]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DiscretePlot` needs expression not list on the left side

[image]

Notice it says expression. i.e. some expression as function of `n` it it, which you do not have. You have list of numbers. If you can find a formula that represent your list of numbers, as function of `n`, then you can use `DiscretePlot`

You can use list plot with Filling->Axis. To get the origin to start where you wanted, one way is to build the `{x,y}` data yourself so it comes out automatically correct without needing to adjust Axes origin.

```
y = {3, -1, 0, -2, 1, -2, -4, 0, 1}
x = Range[-2, Length[y] - 3]
data = Transpose[{x, y}]
ListPlot[data, Mesh -> All, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

If you define your function as:

```
x[-2] = 3; x[-1] = -1; x[0] = 0; x[1] = -2; x[2] = 1; x[3] = -2; x[4] = -4; x[5] = 0;x[6] = 1;
```

You may then using DiscretePlot, writing:

```
DiscretePlot[x[i], {i, -2, 6}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `DiscretePlot`, you can make the function `f` have the values on those inputs:

```
Clear@f
(f[#1] = #2) & @@@ Transpose[{{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, -1, 0, -2, 1, -2, -4, 0, 1}}];
DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, -2, 6}]
```

[image]